# Regular expression C# text without number

Tags: c#, regex

Please give me advice. How to write a regular expression, which allows only letter (without special character or number]? Valid inputs are for example:

- oil, wheat, grain

not allowed for example:

- 1oil, wheat5, grain33

I try to write regular expression this way, but without success:

```
    public bool RegexControlProduct()
    {
        Regex regexObj = new Regex("[a-z]+");
        bool foundmatch = regexObj.IsMatch(subjectstring);
        return foundmatch;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What problem do you get?

Comment: What about spaces and commas in your input?

Comment: When I give to input for example 9oil so it's acceptable

Comment: 9oil isn't allowed, correct? — I think that would be `unacceptable` actually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow anything except numbers, you should do:

`^[^\d]+$`

however, if you want to match the string in the format shown in your question, you can do:

`^[a-zA-Z,\s]+$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/iE2dJ9

Comment: what \s means in this?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, It means a space character `' '`

Comment: Any whitespace character (e.g. `\t`, `\n`), not just the normal space (0x20)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just use [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) with your regex.

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex("^[a-z]+$");
                            ^      ^
```

You may try to use `[a-zA-Z]+` to handle both cases of letters.